# GKE Ingress is not working with cert-manager ssl secrets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-secrets, cert-manager

I am trying to get letsencrypt work with GKE LB, I know there are GCP Managed Certs but it will not work with internal LB as the challenge will not get passed. Letsencrypt DNS certification using cert-manager is there and ready to be used.

```
❯ k get secrets letsencrypt-prod -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.key: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQpNSUlFb3dJQkFBS0NBUUVBdlVZTVhXdGNZZUJpMkdadzljRFRLNzY==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-01-24T15:03:39Z"
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: elastic-system
  resourceVersion: "3636289"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/elastic-system/secrets/letsencrypt-prod
  uid: f4bec5a9-d3b5-4f4a-9ec6-01a4ce3ba47c
type: Opaque
```

```
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - staging.example.com
      - staging2.example.com
      secretName: letsencrypt-prod
```

GCP Reporting this error `Error syncing to GCP: error running load balancer syncing routine: error getting secrets for Ingress: secret "letsencrypt-prod" does not specify cert as string data`

can anybody help me with what it is missing?

Comment: You should not post your private key anywhere, let alone for your production env. But after decoding it looks incomplete anyway. Also, it looks like you haven't added a cert file, which is what the error is telling you. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets

Comment: @QBrute thanks, i intentionally kept it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is missed in doc or I am missing as example uses the same name everywhere as metadata.

```
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: cert-example
  namespace: example
spec:
  secretName: REAL_NAME_OF_SECRET << This need to include in ingress.
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  dnsNames:
  - 'staging.domain.com'
  - '*.staging.domain.com'
```

so `REAL_NAME_OF_SECRET`  you should put in ingress or anywhere, where you want to use `tls.crt` or `tls.key`.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret#from_files), you must provide a valid format for GCP, like this from your already provided `Let's Encrypt` valid certs:

```
kubectl create secret generic letsencrypt-prod --from-file=tls.crt="cert.pem" --from-file=tls.key="privkey.pem" --dry-run -o yaml > output
kubectl apply -f output
```

Also, (it seems you are already using it, but better safe than sorry), you must define this in the `tls` section of your `Ingress` as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl#overview)